# Chart display removes other contents

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

My page has the following html tags and content.

```
<h1>A H1 title</h1>
<p>paragraph something...</p>
```

When I run it, The page appears as expected with the h1 header and paragraph. But when I include a new chart using Razor tag on that page, it removes/covers up the header and paragraph content and only shows the chart on the page. The shared Layout is gone too. How can I show the contents, layout and the chart?

```
<h1>This is a h1 title</h1>
<p>Paragraph something...</p>
@{
    var myChart = new Chart(width: 600, height: 400)
        .AddTitle("Chart Title")
        .AddSeries(
            name: "Employee",
            xValue: new[] { "Peter", "Andrew", "Julie", "Mary", "Dave" },
            yValues: new[] { "2", "6", "4", "5", "3" })
        .Write();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put your chart code in a separate partial view, say `_Chart.cshtml` (include only the code between `@{ ..... }`. Then in the main view, use an `<img>` element to display the chart

_Chart.cshtml

```
@{
  var myChart = new Chart(width: 600, height: 400)
    .AddTitle("Chart Title")
    .AddSeries(
      name: "Employee",
      xValue: new[] { "Peter", "Andrew", "Julie", "Mary", "Dave" },
      yValues: new[] { "2", "6", "4", "5", "3" })
    .Write();
}
```

yourView.cshtml

```
<h1>This is a h1 title</h1>
<p>Paragraph something...</p>
<p><img src="_Chart.cshtml" /> </p>
```

Comment: This answer is correct in this instance but it would only work if I hard code everything. Doesn't work if I want to get the x and y values from a database depending on the content of the yourView.cshtml page. For example the value for x is  model => model.Name and model.Name differs  depending on which page I am on. But guess I should probably ask this in a  different question.

Comment: Then you can create a method in the controller that gets you data and passes it to the partial view and you call the method using `@Html.Action()`. And if you having problems, then yes, you should ask anew question :)